# Ruby Split number in ones or halves

Tags: ruby

I like to split up a score in an array of n positions.

Lets say my score is 11 and the array is of size 12.
Then I like to have some array that is filled with for example 11 ones or 10 ones and 2 halves (0.5). In the end it should sum to 11.

Then the possible scores are:

```rb
size = 12
possible_scores = (0..size).step(0.5).to_a
```

I can create an array of 12 positions:

```rb
scores = Array.new(size) {0}
```

I could pick a random value from the following possible values:

```rb
[0, 0.5, 1].sample
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to retrieve a random array without having lots of state variables if possible. I already tried to do this in a while loop:

```rb
while score < 0
```

and reduce the value of score with the random value and keep track of the array positions that are set. But it became quite a messy piece of code.

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks!

Edit:

For this example I want an array that sums up to 11. So any one of

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0] 

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5] 

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Or whatever combination that sums up to 11.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do, nor why you're trying to do it. What problem are you trying to solve? Why can't you simply fill the array with the score, followed by a bunch of zeroes? (E.g., score 11, array size 4: `[11, 0, 0, 0]`.) Are you trying to make it so that each number is as similar to the others as possible? If so, why not go with `[11/4, 11/4, 11/4, 11/4]`?

Comment: I want an array that sums up to 11 this [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0] OR [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5]. It can only have values 0, 0.5 or 1. I need this to generate test data.

Comment: Your method throws an error if I run it `random_scores(12,11)`

Comment: And it does not return an array of size 12 all the time hmmm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Parameters and variables**

Given:

- `tot`, the desired total, an integer or an odd multiple of `0.5`; and
- `size`, the total number of `0`'s, `0.5`'s and `1`'s that total `tot`, with the requirement that `size >= tot`.

we define three variables:

- `n0` equals the number of zeroes;
- `n0pt5_pairs` equals the number of pairs of `0.5`'s; and
- `n1` equals the number of ones.

**Case 1: `tot` is an integer**

We require:

```
0 <= n0pt5_pairs <= [tot, size-tot].min
```

Note that because `n1 = tot - n0pt5_pairs`, `2 * n0pt5_pairs + n1 = n0pt5_pairs + tot > size` if `n0pt5_pairs > size-tot`. That is, the total number of `0.5`'s and ones exceeds `size` if the number of `0.5` pairs exceeds `size-tot`.

Given a value for `n0pt5_pairs` that satisfies the above requirement, `n0` and `n1` are determined:

```
n1 = tot - n0pt5_pairs
n0 = size - 2*n0pt5_pairs - n1
   = size - tot - n0pt5_pairs
```

We can therefore randomly select a random triple `[n0, 2*n0pt5_pairs, n1]` as follows:

```
def random_combo(size, tot)
  n0pt5_pairs = rand(1+[tot, size-tot].min)
  [size-tot-n0pt5_pairs, 2*n0pt5_pairs, tot-n0pt5_pairs]
end
```

For example:

```
arr = random_combo(17, 11)
  #=> [3, 6, 8]
```

This is used to generate the array

```
arr1 = [*[0]*arr[0], *[0.5]*arr[1], *[1]*arr[2]]
  #=> [0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

which we shuffle:

```
arr1.shuffle
  #=> [1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5]
```

Note `arr1.size #=> 17` and `arr.sum #=> 11`.

**Case 2: `tot` is a multiple of 0.5**

If

```
tot = n + 0.5
```

where `n` is an integer, every combination of `0`'s, `0.5`'s and `1`'s will have at least one `0.5`. We therefore can compute the number of `0`'s and `1`'s, together with the number of `0.5`'s *in excess of one*. To do that we simply reduce `tot` by `0.5` (making it equal to an integer) and `size` by one, use `generate_for_integer` to solve that problem, then for each three-element array returned by that method increase the number of `0.5`'s by one.

```
def generate(size, tot)
  return nil if size.zero?
  is_int = (tot == tot.floor)
  tot = tot.floor
  size -= 1 unless is_int 
  n0pt5_pairs = rand(1+[tot, size-tot].min)
  [*[0]*(size-tot-n0pt5_pairs), *[0.5]*(2*n0pt5_pairs + (is_int ? 0 : 1)),
   *[1]*(tot-n0pt5_pairs)].
  shuffle
end
```

```
ge = generate(17, 10)
  #=> [0, 1, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5] 
ge.size #=> 17 
ge.sum  #=> 10.0 

go = generate(17, 10.5)
  #=> [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0] 
go.size #=> 17 
go.sum  #=> 10.5
```

Comment: Thanks Cary, this also works just like I was looking for. I was thinking about calculating of maximum number of 0.5's and 1's on my way home I had not jet figured out how but that's just what you have done here. But I prefer the answer of Aleksei Matiushkin because of its simplicity.

Comment: I ran this method and the version of Aleksei and this version is more efficient it uses less memory and runs faster. But when I test this version with tot = 9.5 then the sum of the array it returns is 9 or 9.0. Perhaps I did not mention the score input could/should be a Float.

Comment: My solution is premised on the total being an integer and `0`, `0.5` and `1` being the possible values. I'll think about it but I'm doubtful there's an easy fix for my answer.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention sorry about that. I like the efficiency of your approach but unfortunately I needed to input floats as well.

Comment: Would it work with multiples of 0.5 for `tot` if you doubled all of the inputs and then halved the outputs?

Comment: @Jordan, that ran through my mind as well. The problem is that if you ended up with an odd number of `1`'s you are left with a fractional number of `1`'s after dividing by `2`. If you reduce that number of (doubled) `1`'s by one and increase the number of doubled pairs of `0.5`'s by one the sum still equals `tot`. After dividing by two, however, the number of elements goes from `size` to `size+1`. If there is at least one zero the number of zeroes can be reduced by one, but if there are no zeroes it's a dead end. Even if there is at least one zero, randomness is lost.

Comment: Smek and @JordanRunning, I've modified my answer to deal with the case where `tot` can be an odd multiple of `0.5`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Nice work. I just posted an answer that you might be interested in. 

Comment: Based on suggestions made by @JordanRunning (including a comment he made on his answer), I've simplified and improved the efficiency of my answer considerably. Thanks, Jordan!

Comment: Cool benchmarked 1000000 times: Time: 3.45 Memory: 10.02 MB! Sorry I'm a performance fetishist i guess.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby provides all you require here, no need to write any algorithmic code. [`Array#repeated_combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-repeated_combination) is your friend here:

```
[0, 0.5, 1].
  repeated_combination(12).    # 91 unique variant
  to_a.                        # unfortunately it cannot be lazy
  shuffle.                     # to randomize array outcome
  detect { |a| a.sum == 11 }.
  shuffle                      # to randomize numbers inside array
#⇒ [0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

---

*Sidenote:* one might avoid the necessity to shuffle twice (both array of generated arrays and the resulting array) by using [`Array#repeated_permutation`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation), but this would drastically increase memory load and execution time.

Comment: This is the perfect answer just what I was after. Both shuffles are needed to get a combination of 0's, 1's and 0.5's otherwise I would get only 1's and 0's for even numbers. Thanks Aleksei!

Comment: `a.sum` raises `NoMethodError: undefined method `sum'` in Ruby < 2.4.1

Comment: This is clever and works well as long as `[0,0.5,1].repeated_combination(n).to_a.size` is not to great. For `n=100` it's `5151`, for `n=500`, it's `125751`, for `n=1000` it's `501501`, for `n=10_000`, it's (I'll get back to you).

Comment: @CarySwoveland remove the `to_a` and utilize the enumerator's ability to calculate its [`size`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-size) lazily ;-)

Comment: @Stefan unfortunately, `shuffle` is defined on array but not on enumerable.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin indeed, but creating all 91 combinations in order to find the 2 which sum to 11 seems a bit wasteful.

Comment: @Stefan I thought about calculating the `size = 91` and lazy doing [contrived] `loop { i = rand(0...size); break combs[i].shuffle if combs[i].sum == 11 }` but it would overcomplicate the code and be less random due to different intervals between matches.

Answer (score 3):

I like Cary Swoveland's answer, but in fact this can be done without generating an array of solutions.

Let's consider a few examples.

Given size = 6 and score = 3, *without* shuffling, these are the possible outputs (numbered on the left for reasons that will become apparent):

```
i               ones halves zeroes
0│ 1 1 1 0 0 0    3     0      3
1│ 1 1 ½ ½ 0 0    2     2      2
2│ 1 ½ ½ ½ ½ 0    1     4      1
3│ ½ ½ ½ ½ ½ ½    0     6      0
```

Given size = 6 and score = 3.5:

```
i               ones halves zeroes
0│ 1 1 1 ½ 0 0    3     1      2
1│ 1 1 ½ ½ ½ 0    2     3      1
2│ 1 ½ ½ ½ ½ ½    1     5      0
```

Given size = 11 and score = 4.5:

```
i                         ones halves zeroes
0│ 1 1 1 1 ½ 0 0 0 0 0 0    4     1      6
1│ 1 1 1 ½ ½ ½ 0 0 0 0 0    3     3      5
2│ 1 1 ½ ½ ½ ½ ½ 0 0 0 0    2     5      4
3│ 1 ½ ½ ½ ½ ½ ½ ½ 0 0 0    1     7      3
4│ ½ ½ ½ ½ ½ ½ ½ ½ ½ 0 0    0     9      2
```

Given size = 12 and score = 11:

```
i                            ones halves zeroes
0│ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0    11     0      1
1│ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ½ ½    10     2      0
```

Can you see the patterns? After a bit of chin-scratching we discover the following facts:

1. The number of possible outputs  for a given *size* and *score* is given by:

   > ＝ min(⌊*score*⌋, *size* − ⌈*score*⌉) + 1
2. As  increases, the number of ones decreases. The number of ones is given by:

   > count(1) ＝ ⌊*score*⌋ −
3. As  increases, the number of halves (½) increases. The number of halves is given by:

   > count(½) ＝ 2( + mod(*score*, 1))

   In other words, it's 2 + 1 if *score* has a fractional part, or 2 otherwise.
4. As  increases, the number of zeroes decreases, given by:

   > count(0) ＝ *size* − ⌈*score*⌉ −

With these four facts in mind we can generate any of the  possible outputs at random by picking a random  where 0 ≤  < :

> = random( [0..) )

These facts are easy to translate into Ruby code:

```
n = [score.floor, size - score.ceil].min + 1
i = rand(n)
num_ones = score.floor - i
num_halves = 2 * (i + score % 1)
num_zeroes = (size - score.floor) - i
```

Now we just need to clean it up a bit and put it in a function that takes `size` and `score` as arguments, turns `num_ones`, `num_halves`, and `num_zeroes` into an array of `0`s, `0.5`s, and `1`s, and shuffles the result:

```
def generate(size, score)
  init_ones = score.floor
  init_zeroes = size - score.ceil

  i = rand([init_ones, init_zeroes].min + 1)
  num_ones = init_ones - i
  num_halves = 2 * (i + score % 1)
  num_zeroes = init_zeroes - i

  [ *[1]*num_ones, *[0.5]*num_halves, *[0]*num_zeroes ].shuffle
end

generate(6, 3.5)
# => [0.5, 1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1]
```

You can see the result in action on repl.it: https://repl.it/@jrunning/UnpleasantDimpledLegacysystem (Note that when you run it on repl.it the output appears very slowly. This is only because repl.it executes Ruby code on the server and streams the result back to the browser.)

Comment: Very nicely done! I particularly like your examples at the beginning, which makes it easy to follow the code later. Two small things: 1) I don't actually generate permutations; I just map the range `0..[tot, size-tot].min`. 2) you might replace `score.integer?` with `score == score.floor` to permit `score` being entered as (for example), `11.0`. Without thinking about it too hard I expect our solutions are actually quite similar.

Comment: Oops. For some reason I thought `integer?` returned `true` for e.g. `11.0`. I'll fix that. Thanks!

Comment: @CarySwoveland "Permutations" was the wrong word, of course. I've changed the language I used there. As I'm wont to do I benchmarked these three solutions: https://repl.it/@jrunning/GainsboroTrainedCells It shakes out about how you'd expect, I think.

Comment: And you're right, our solutions are extremely similar. The main difference is that I figured out how to pick an iteration of your `map` at random without generating any of the other iterations. I suspect you'd have arrived at the same thing given more time.

Comment: Not necessarily, I have many blind spots. I'll edit my answer to incorporate that suggestion.

Comment: I re-ran your benchmark with my updated code (that incorporates your idea of doing just one random selection). Not surprisingly, my code runs neck-and-neck with yours.

Comment: You can calculate `num_halves` much simpler: `num_halves = size - num_ones - num_zeroes`. And you could reduce the number of variables by modifying them, i.e. `ones = score.floor` and later on `ones -= i` (no need to keep the initial values).

Comment: Very nice it uses more memory than the solution of Aleksei Matiushkin but it runs faster. I ran a benchmark 1.000.000 times: Time: 10.97 Memory: 16.18 MB vs Time: 191.41 Memory: 4.24 MB. MAybe reducing the number of variables like Stefan suggest helps reducing memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

If I get the point, one possible option could be (brute force)

```
size = 12
sum = 11
tmp = Array.new(12){1}

loop do
  raise 'not possible' if tmp.sum < sum
  tmp[tmp.index(1)] = 0.5 if tmp.index(1)
  unless tmp.index(1)
    tmp[tmp.index(0.5)] = 0
  end
  break if tmp.sum == sum
end

tmp #=> [0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
tmp.sum #=> 11.0
```

Comment: That comes close to what I want but I rather have something that does not raise an exception. I want something that generates a random array I did not mention that before sorry for that.

Comment: Maybe adding `shuffle` At the end.

Comment: Indeed shuffle does that thanks. I have a solution that works see my question. Don't know if it can be improved but it works.